# Formatting live template variables in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, live-templates

I have a live template for creating directives in angular, and one of the things I'd like to do to make it easier to use is copy the dependency array in the controller declaration for the directive into the parameters for the controller function. The problem is that the dependency array requires the parameters to be strings, so one might look like `['$scope', '$location', 'etcService', controllerName]` where the parameters are everything in the array before the controller name. The controller function where I want to inject those parameters would be `function controllerName($scope, $location, etcService){}`

In order to do this you can see I need to remove the quotes around each array element. Is this possible to do in live templates?

Here is my current template:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('$moduleName$');

    app.controller('$controllerName$', [$PARAMS$, $controllerName$]);

    app.directive('$directiveName$', function () {

        return {
            templateUrl: 'app/$templateUrl$',
            transclude: $transclude$,
            restrict: '$restrict$',
            scope: $scope$,
            controller: $controllerName$
        }
    });

    function $controllerName$($PARAMS_noQuotes$){
    $END$
    }
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible using Live Templates as it has no "replace" functions that would allow replacing `'` by nothing (to do your desired transformation).

Comment: I have not found any dedicated ticket where such functionality is requested; only partially related comments [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55066#comment=27-158738) or [another partially related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7122). It definitely makes sense to submit separate ticket -- much better chance that particular functionality will be implemented sooner (will not get lost): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Thanks very much, @LazyOne. It's unfortunate this is not possible, it seems like it should be a standard feature.

Comment: "Standard" is pretty questionable in this context. I, for example, have not had any need to have it there. And based on tickets that I managed to find, only few people mentioned "would be good to have" without even providing their use cases. But yes -- nobody will be against having such functionality available there.

Comment: I'm not Angular user .. so don't know much about where such functions are used etc. So my question is -- can you have multiple code blocks like that in single file .. or it's more likely to have single block per file? If single block .. then maybe you should try File Template instead? It's not ideal (Velocity templating engine) .. but at least you can use basic Java's string manipulation functions there...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible using Live Templates as it has no "replace" functions that would allow replacing characters (in your case: `'` by nothing) to do your desired transformation.

---

I have not found any dedicated ticket where such functionality is requested; only partially related comments [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55066#comment=27-158738) or another [partially related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7122).

It definitely makes sense to **submit separate ticket (Feature Request)** -- much better chance that particular functionality will be implemented sooner (and will not get lost): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve such functionality with predefined function groovyScript. It is documented only briefly: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates-2.html but it is an alternative for more complicated live template manipulation.

Let's define the simplified live template named 'ctrl':

```
app.controller('$controllerName$', [$PARAMS$, $controllerName$]);

function $controllerName$($PARAMS_noQuotes$){
    $END$
}
```

Variables for the live template could look like this (notice that PATH_TO_GROOVY_SCRIPT have to be manually exchanged to full path to groovy script!):

[image: Edit Template Variables dialog]

Live template scripts can be stored as scratches:

[image: Scratches]

In this case "PATH_TO_GROOVY_SCRIPT" would be:

```
"<YOUR_INTELLIJ_HOME>\\config\\scratches\\Live Templates\\ctrl\\PARAMS_noQuotes.groovy"
```

Actual script can be very simple e.g.:

```
"$_1".replaceAll("'","")
```

In my opinion even in such a simple case it is a good practice to use separate script files instead of inline script expression in variable dialog. Separate scripts have this advantage they can be easily tested in Groovy Console...

Ready template can be used like this:

[image: Live Template in use]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where it was implemented, but as of not it's possible to replace any string using regular expressions with

```
regularExpression(<String>, <Pattern>, <Replacement>)
```

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html#predefined_functions